# How do I calculate all possible combinations for a player creator in a game?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

I'm currently working on a character creator for a game, but I don't know how to calculate all possible character combinations the player can create. In the creator, the player is required to choose exactly one from each option to create 1 character:
- 6 hats
- 10 noses
- 6 glases
- 3 sticks
- 31 hairstyles
- 8 hair colors
- 3 swords
- 15 pants
- 21 shirts

Just to rephrase it: To create 1 character, every player is required to choose a combination of: 1x hat, 1x nose, 1 glases, 1 stick, 1 hairstyle, 1 hair color, 1 sword, 1 pants, 1 shirt

I would calculate the number of possible characters using the following equation:
6x10x6x3x31x8x3x15x21 = 253,108,800 combinations

Is my calculation correct? Am I missing something?

Comment: Your calculations look correct.

Answer (score 1):

As Milo noted in a comment, your calculations look correct. You're applying what is known as the [rule of product or the multiplication principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product).